# How to display entire row of selected value in Shiny?

Tags: shiny, drop-down-menu

How to display the entire row of a selected value?

What we have is a drop down menu where a certain values of a defined column can be selected. If one of the values in the the drop down menu is selected the entire row where this value is located should be displayed.

In the following case the values that can be selected in a drop down menu are the letters x, y, z. e.g. If "y" is selected in the drop down menu, it should be displayed only the entire second row inlcuding the column names.

```
library(shiny)

Values <- data.frame(A = 1:3, B = letters[24:26], C = 11:13)

shinyApp(
ui = fluidPage(        
    sidebarPanel(
        selectInput("Values", "Values", Values$B),            
    mainPanel(
        tableOutput("ValuesTable")
        )
    )
),

server = function(input, output) {    
    output$ValuesTable <- renderTable({
        Values
    })    
})
```

What I´ve found so far are solutions with `_rows_selected`. However, it doesn´t fit to my problem or I´m not able to make use of it, yet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can filter values in the appropriate column using `dplyr::filter()` with your select input "Values" in the `renderTable()` function.

```
library(shiny)
library(dplyr) # for filter() function
library(magrittr) # for pipe operator

Values <- data.frame(A = 1:3, B = letters[24:26], C = 11:13)

shinyApp(
  ui = fluidPage(        
    sidebarPanel(
      selectInput("Values", "Values", Values$B),            
      mainPanel(
        tableOutput("ValuesTable")
      )
    )
  ),
  
  server = function(input, output) {    
    output$ValuesTable <- renderTable({
      Values %>% 
        dplyr::filter(B == input$Values)
    })    
  })
```

Comment: thanks a lot for your fast answer! it works :)